# Problem When Using More Than Two Wildcards

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that will take specified letters and wildcard characters(`'*'`) and check them against words in a list to print all available matches. I have written the below code which will work when two wildcard characters are used:

```
def wildcard_search(letters, count):
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    words = ['hello', 'hi', 'good', 'help', 'hellos', 'helloing', 'hallow', 'no']
    count = 0
    wild_loc = []

    while count < len(letters):
        for letter in letters:
            if letter == '*':
                wild_loc.append(count)
                count += 1

    for letter in alpha:
        new_letters = letters[:wild_loc[1]].replace('*', letter)

        for each in words:
                    each = each.strip('')

            if new_letters in each:
                holder = new_letters

                for letter in alpha:
                    new_letters = letters[wild_loc[1]:].replace('*', letter)

                    for each in words:
                        each = each.strip('')

                        if holder + new_letters in each:
                             print each
```

My question is, how do I write this code to return results when more than two wildcard characters are used? I have tried using the below while loop, but I end up with an index out of range error:

```
count = 0
store = ''
while count <= len(wild_loc)-1:
    for letter in alpha:
        if count != len(wild_loc) - 1:
            new_letter = letters[:wild_loc[count]].replace('*', letter)
            for each in words:
                each = each.strip('')
                if new_letter in each:
                    res = store + new_letter
                    store = new_letter
            count += 1

        elif count == len(wild_loc) - 1:
            new_letter = letters[wild_loc[count]:].replace('*', letter)
            for each in words:
                each = each.strip('')
                if (res + new_letter) in each:
                    print each
            count += 1
```

Comment: Can you just use regular expressions or [`fnmatch.filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter)? It'll work better, and I'm sure be faster.

Comment: +1 on chmullig's answer, worst case, you could "preprocess" the search string and turn it into a regex. For instance, you might not want to allow users to have to specify full regexs, so instead, you tell them to use "*" for any chars match, then you replace all * in the input string with .* and perform a regex search.

Comment: +1 chmullig, the `fnmatch.filter` does indeed work. Thanks I had stumbled upon `fnmatch` but did not see a way to make it work until now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fnmatch.filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter). Basically, it implements shell-like pattern matching using the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), and does exactly what you want.